# Constant term after integration

Tags: calculus, vectors

I am doing some vector calculus which involves finding gradients of surfaces etc. In one of the problems such as::

$$\frac{d\phi}{dx} = x^2-y+x $$

And I'm doing its integration to get $\phi$:

$$\phi = \frac{x^3}{3}-xy^2 + \phi_1(y,z) $$

Why would I have $\phi_1(y,z)$ instead of $C$ if anyone has any idea?

Comment: If you are intregrating with respect to $x$, the you shouldn't have an $xy^2$ term. It should be $xy$

Answer (score 1):

Because any function taking $y$ and/or $z$ but not $x$ as arguments will be considered as a constant while differentiating with respect to $x$, so that your integration constant is a function of $y$ and $z$.

If you have

\begin{equation}\frac{\text{d}\phi(x,y,z)}{\text{d}x}=x^{2}+x-y\hspace{10em}(1)\end{equation}

It gives

$$\phi(x,y,z)=\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-yx+\phi_{1}(y,z)$$

where $\phi_{1}(y,z)$ is a function of $y$ and $z$. For example, take $\phi_{1}(y,z)=y^{z}$ or $\phi_{1}(y,z)=8$ and you will see that you'll get $(1)$ when differentiating with repect to $x$.